# Custom tool tip in ag-grid angular is partially visible

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to implement custom tool tip in ag-grid, but the tooltip is partially visible.

For reference, i have source code present in Plunker. There are two ag-arid instances as an example. If you mouse over on first ag-grid on first column of last row, tooltip is partially visible.

is there a way to show full content of tooltip.

link to the code: 'http://plnkr.co/edit/QBfY00iJ8sxkZqym'

[Updated Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkcJf.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a height on the `:host` selector in your custom tooltip component. E.g. set it to `300px`, then the tooltip should display above your mouse pointer when on the last row, allowing it be completely visible.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kr9wRY5bvI79JlLi).

Comment: Thank you @ViqMontana for the response, my text in tool tip is dynamic so not sure how to set the correct height. Also, In my page i need to display multiple ag- grid, few of the grids will have only 2-3 records/rows but the tooltip might be of 500px or more height in this case also the tool tip is visible partially. is there a way to resolve this. Appreciate your help. thanks a ton!

Comment: i have updated the code replicating my issue as said above. http://plnkr.co/edit/QBfY00iJ8sxkZqym

Answer (score 0):

Try the following style in your tooltip style class:

```
z-index: 9999 !important;
overflow: visible !important;
white-space: normal !important;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).